# I need help understanding the coded solution for getting quotients and remainders. It is using an array and recursion to solve the problem

Tags: java, recursion

I am having trouble following how this code snippet recursively solves the problem. For one, I would like to write out the steps that are being taken by the program, but I am confused as to how it is arriving to the solution. For example, quotientandremainder(13,2). I know that it doesn't meet the base case so therefore the program will run 1 + output[0], output[1]. In the output call it seems that it is subtracting 13 and 2, and the divisor remains? How is the (13,2) really calculated to achieve the end result? I really would like to grock this as I'm trying to understand recursion and I am finding it difficult, the struggle is real. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
public class QuotientAndRemainder
{
public static int[] quotientAndRemainder(int dividend,int divisor)
{
if(dividend<divisor)
return new int[]{0,dividend};
int[] output=quotientAndRemainder(dividend-divisor,divisor);
return new int[]{1 + output[0],output[1]};
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int[] result=quotientAndRemainder(13,2);
System.out.printf("%s divided by %s is %s and remainder is %s\n",13,2,result[0],result[1]);
result=quotientAndRemainder(2,13);
System.out.printf("%s divided by %s is %s and remainder is %s\n",2,13,result[0],result[1]);
result=quotientAndRemainder(75,5);
System.out.printf("%s divided by %s is %s and remainder is %s\n",75,5,result[0],result[1]);
}
}
```

Comment: Why the C tag to a non-C question?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Why not remove the C tag when it's obviously wrong?

Comment: @4386427 Seemed courteous to give OP a chance to explain their position first.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well, fine... Maybe I should have waited a bit but IMO it seems obvious that this has nothing to do with C

Comment: "For one, I would like to write out the steps that are being taken by the program..." So why don't you add print statement inside the recursive function?

Comment: I really, really, really suggest you read about [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#K&R_style). Add spaces at the beginning of each line to reflect the hierarchic structure of the program. I assure you it will make your code much easier to read and reason about, both for you and for other people.

Answer (score 0):

It seems someone implemented a division just the way it is taught at school.
When you run the application, it starts executing in the main() method. The first line in there says

```
result=quotientAndRemainder(13,2)
```

so your method is trying to check how many times 2 is contained in 13. It does this recursively until it finds on the seventh reentry that 1 is less than 2, returning [0, 1].
This will be added to the previous level which was called as quotientAndRemainder(3,2) and will return [1, 1].
This recursively bubbles up the other levels and sums up to [6, 1], which is the final result being returned to the main method.